# Separate searchview for fragments

Tags: android, fragment, searchview

I have a simple activity which holds a tabbar to switch two fragments. The two fragments are both a listFragment and implement a searchview to make searching possible within the listfragment. The searchview is always shown in the actionbar above the tabbar.

The problem I have is that the input of the searchview isn’t reset once I switch the tab (go to other fragment). Therefore, the second fragment reads the input from the searchview and filters the listfragment accordingly, which actually reads the input I entered when I was still in fragment one.

What I want is the searchview to be a separate searchview for both fragments. Is there a way to  achieve this?

Here is my code:

**Activity**

```
public class ActivityMainApp extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.mainapp);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Add tabs
    ActionBar.Tab relatieTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Relaties");
    ActionBar.Tab takenTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Taken");
    //ActionBar.Tab urenTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Uren");

    // Listeners 
    relatieTab.setTabListener(this);
    takenTab.setTabListener(this);

    // Tabs toevoegen aan actionbar
actionBar.addTab(relatieTab);
actionBar.addTab(takenTab);

    // Create fragmentmanager to switch fragments
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);

    if(fragment == null){
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new FragRelaties());
    }

}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(tab.getText().equals("Taken")){
        FragTaken fragment = new FragTaken();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    if(tab.getText().equals("Relaties")){
        FragRelaties fragment = new FragRelaties();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

}
```

**Fragment one**

```
public class FragRelaties extends ListFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ModelRelatie modelRelatie;
private AdapterRelatie relatieAdapter;
public ArrayList<Relatie> relaties;

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.inflater = inflater;

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        final Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Relatie>>(){

            protected ArrayList<Relatie> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // Get all my contacts
                modelRelatie = ModelRelatie.instantiate(context);
                ArrayList<Relatie> relaties = modelRelatie.getRelaties();

                return relaties;

            }
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Relatie> relaties) {

                // Initial input of objects in the list
                relatieAdapter = new AdapterRelatie(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.relatieslijstitem, relaties);
                setListAdapter(relatieAdapter);

            }

        }.execute();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relaties, container, false);

        return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {

inflater.inflate(R.menu.relatie_menu, menu);

            // Get the searchview
    MenuItem zoekveld = menu.findItem(R.id.zoekveld_fragrelatie);
    SearchView zoekview = (SearchView) zoekveld.getActionView();

    // Execute this when searching
    zoekview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   // Things that happen when i click on an item in the list
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String zoekterm) {

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    // We start searching for the name entered
    ModelRelatie modelRelatie = ModelRelatie.instantiate(context);
    ArrayList<Relatie> relaties = modelRelatie.zoekRelatie(zoekterm);

    // The returned objects are placed in the list
    this.relatieAdapter = new AdapterRelatie(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.relatieslijstitem, relaties);
    setListAdapter(relatieAdapter);

    return true;

}
```

**Fragment Two**

```
public class FragTaken extends ListFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private AdapterTaak adapterTaak;
private ModelTaken modelTaken;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.inflater = inflater;

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        final Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        this.modelTaken = ModelTaken.instantiate(context);
        ArrayList<Taak> taken = modelTaken.getTaken();

        // Initial input for the list
        adapterTaak = new AdapterTaak(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.takenlijstitem, taken);
        setListAdapter(adapterTaak);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taken, container, false);
        return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {

inflater.inflate(R.menu.taken_menu, menu);

    // get the searview
    MenuItem zoekveld = menu.findItem(R.id.zoekveld_fragtaken);
    SearchView zoekview = (SearchView) zoekveld.getActionView();

    // Execute this when searching
    zoekview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String zoekterm) {

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    // Search the task by the inputed value
    ModelTaken modelTaken = ModelTaken.instantiate(context);
    ArrayList<Taak> taken = modelTaken.zoekTaak(zoekterm);

    // Return the found items to the list
    this.adapterTaak = new AdapterTaak(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.takenlijstitem, taken);
    setListAdapter(adapterTaak);

    return true;

}

}
```

Both fragments are almost identical except the searching part.

Comment: Stuck on same problem. Its quite a while but if you have come up with any answer,please post it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its been quite a while but still if anyone is finding the same problem,
here's how i managed to do that .

Just implement **onPrepareOptionsMenu()** in each of your fragments and
inside of it, call 
**onQueryTextChange("");**  passing "" as query string.

Comment: We eventually dropped the idea of using a searchview. Instead we added our own edittext just below the statusbar to achieve a similar result. Thanks for anwering anyway!

Comment: Hi it's seems helpful,Can u please elaborate this.

Comment: Thank you, but should change onQueryTextChange("") to searchView.setQuery("", true)

Comment: how you access that way in navigation drwer?

Comment: @frank1fr If using edittext instead of searchview, can you click search button in the soft keyboard to submit our search?